# Assigning CLLocationManager delegate when creating the CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, variables

How can i do the following without errors? The line `locationManager.delegate = self` says it cannot `Cannot assign value of type '(APPLocationManager) -> () -> (APPLocationManager)' to type 'CLLocationManagerDelegate?'`

```
let locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.other
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
    locationManager.distanceFilter = APPLocationManagerDistanceFilter

    return locationManager
}()
```

I want the delegate to be the instance of the class that the `locationManager` property is part of.

Comment: At your first line. Change let to lazy var

Answer (score 1):

You should Assign your delegate object to the delegate property of the [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate) object before starting any services.
as -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.other
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
        locationManager.distanceFilter = APPLocationManagerDistanceFilter

        return locationManager
    }()
```